What is being said here that implies being less violent/hotheaded (expression involving 猫{ねこ}?)
In Ginga Eiyuu Densetsu, Fredrica Greenhill (a normally very kind and nice lady) reunites with Julian Minci (who's also very mild-mannered and nice). For context, both are part of the military.
After making sure Julian was still a nice boy, Fredrica surprises him by saying she would've slapped him if he were otherwise. She explains "アタシは子供{こども}の頃{ころ}手{て}が早{はや}いことで有名{ゆうめい}だったんだから。" (back when I was a kid, I was famously quick-tempered). Julian says that's hard to believe, and then Fredrica further explains "そりゃ軍隊{ぐんたい}に入{はい}ってからはおしとやかに(?)neko no ke ga osanyon mae wa kikondeita mono(?)" I don't understand what's being said that I wrote in ro-maji (and not even sure I transcribed it right), but it seems like an expression I'm not familiar with.
Here's a clip of the scene: https://files.catbox.moe/6wftnq.mp4
I know a few cat-related expressions, like 猫の手を借りたい and 猫の額{ひたい}, but I don't know (and couldn't find) anything about 猫の毛{け}.

She says 猫の毛皮を三、四枚は着込んでいたもの in reference to the saying 猫を被る. But I'm not sure this request is on-topic.
